# Sort the values in the jQuery Autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an array like

```
["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC","ALASKA","MADERA", "ANDERSON"]
```

where I'm populating them in a [**`jQuery UI Autocomplete`**](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default).  However the order of sorting seems to be weird.
**For example:**(But I have more no.of records) When I type **"a"** it returns

```
JOAQUIN
BERNARDINO
ALASKA
MADERA
ANDERSON
```

What I'm trying is to get (**starting with**)

```
ALASKA    
ANDERSON
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/5/) for my example

Is it possible?  Can someone point me in a right direction.

**Updates:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var myarray= ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC","ALASKA","MADERA", "ANDERSON"]
myarray.sort();
```

[**Read More**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml#.UjvLpn80qho)

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/14/)

we are passing two arguments into source one is `request` and second is `response`,

- `request` is stands for request object we are making, in our case it is
  the letter we are typing into textbox.
- `response` is function which
  will return us auto complete selection options.

now inside `$.map` we are checking typed words with array we have named json.

`json.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase())` this line convert typed word and array to same case and return it.

and matches would be the final result which has list of item that you have asked.

and `response(matches);` will send it to autocomplete.

Comment: if you read my question, I'm trying to show something like **startwith**.  I have updated a sample screenshot.

Comment: @user1671639 we have read your question and Dipesh did exact as you want `startwith` when type `a` word display which start with `a`. i have also check demo of dipesh.

Comment: @user1671639 see i have modified demo...is that you meaning..?

Comment: Thank you @DipeshParmar. How can I complete the list of results with the words which contain the researched term ? Like if I type "a" I get "alaska, anderson, bernardino, joaquin, madera"

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue with objects rather than simple string array, and sorting needs to be done after retrieving the results (to achieve "startswith" suggestions at the top of the list). so for future searchers, i'll add my solution.

using JQuery you can search for strings within your results object's .label that start with the user input, and merge the rest of the result to those, after merging use Underscore.js library to remove duplicates.

for example:

```
var objects_array = [{"label":"A_ABC","value":"0"},{"label":"B_ABC","value":"1"},{"label":"C_ABC","value":"2"}];

$(document).ready ( function() {

$('#search').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {

        var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(objects_array, request.term);               

        var top_suggestions = $.grep(results, function (n,i) {
                                 return (n.label.substr(0, request.term.length).toLowerCase() == request.term.toLowerCase());
                              });

        var merged_results = $.merge(top_suggestions,results);

        var final_results = _.uniq(merged_results,"label");

        response(final_results);
    }
});

});
```

[image: jquery ui starts with]

result example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKJ8d.png

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
<input type='text' />


var json = ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC","ALASKA","MADERA", "ANDERSON", "KINGSTONE"].sort();
$('input').autocomplete({
  source: json
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/5/

[image]

Comment: if you read my question, I'm trying to show something like startwith. I have updated a sample screenshot.   Hope you understand.

Comment: pressing `k` should returned **KINGSTONE** first.

Comment: I think it is not downvoted, In this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/15/, if you enter "a" it is returning in reverse order.Anyway +1 I appreciate your effort

Comment: This does not work, if you type A it will give you MADERA, JOAQUIN, BERNARDINO, ALASKA, ANDERSON in that order which is all wrong it does not do start with at all. You got king-stone first due to luck on what was in the item list.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an [Example](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1) in the API documentation that touches on what you requested. Here is my (somewhat shortened) take on a solution:

```js
var json = ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC", "ALASKA", "MADERA", "ANDERSON"].sort();
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    // Escape regex
    var term = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
    // Search results that start with the search term
    var matcher1 = new RegExp("^" + term, "i");
    // Search results that start differently
    var matcher2 = new RegExp("^.+" + term, "i");

    function subarray(matcher) {
        return $.grep(json, function(item) {
            return matcher.test(item);
        });
    }
    response($.merge(subarray(matcher1), subarray(matcher2)));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for ajax/JSON results as well and now the right arrow key also fills the input

```
function inlineAutoComplete(auto_complete_input, json) {
    var elem = auto_complete_input;
    jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete]').remove();
    jQuery(elem).parent().append('<span data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '" class="inline-auto-complete" style="display:none"></span>');
    jQuery(elem).keyup(function(ev, ui) {
        if(jQuery(this).val() != '')
            jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-inline-autocomplete]').show();

        if(ev.which == 13 || ev.which == 39) {
            jQuery(this).val( jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-inline-autocomplete] em').text() );
            jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-inline-autocomplete]').hide();
            return;
        }

        var term = jQuery(this).val();

        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + term);
        if (typeof json === 'string' || json instanceof String) {
           jQuery.ajax({
                url: json ,
                data: { term: term },
                success: function(response) {
                    jQuery.each(response.json, function(i, item) {
                        if(matcher.test(item)) {
                            jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '"]').show();
                            jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '"]').html('<em class="d-block">' + item + '</em>');
                            return;
                        } else {
                            jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-inline-autocomplete]').hide();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            jQuery.each(json, function(i, item) {
                if(matcher.test(item)) {
                    jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '"]').show();
                    jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '"]').html('<em class="d-block">' + item + '</em>');
                    return;
                } else {
                    jQuery(this).parent().find('[data-inline-autocomplete]').hide();
                }
            });
        }
        jQuery('[data-inline-autocomplete="' + elem + '"]').click(function(ev) {
                    ev.stopPropagation();
                    jQuery(elem).val(jQuery(this).text());
                    jQuery(this).hide();
        });

    });
}
```